# Removing a specific node from JSON data

Tags: php, json

I'd like to delete a specific node from my JSON file using PHP.

Currently I'm using the following PHP code:

```
<?php
$file = 'data2.json';
$json_data = file_get_contents($file);
$json = json_decode($json_data, true);

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['id']=='ajson2') {
         unset ($value[$key]);
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
}
?>
```

And have the following JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "id": "ajson0",
        "parentNode": "add",
        "name": "Root",
        "type": "folder"
    },
    {
        "id": "ajson2",
        "parentNode": "ajson0",
        "name": "ggg",
        "type": "test"
    },
    {
        "id": "ajson3",
        "parentNode": "ajson0",
        "name": "dvvd",
        "type": "test"
    }
]
```

But currently it does not delete the node from the JSON data.

Comment: As stated below, you should definitely change 'unset($value[$key]);' to 'unset($json[$key]);'. To double check it, use your 'echo' outside the foreach cycle.

Comment: No, it won't work.
Anyway here's the right code:
'<?php
$file = 'data2.json';
$json_data = file_get_contents($file);
$json = json_decode($json_data, true);
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
 
  if ($value['id']=='ajson2']) {
   unset ($json[$key]);
  }
 
 file_put_contents($file, json_encode($json));
}'

?>

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this,

```
$file = 'ico1.json';
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file),true);
foreach ($json as $key => &$value) {

$sKey = array_search('ajson2', $value);
if ($sKey!==false) {
    unset($value[$sKey]);
}
}
$json = json_encode($json);
```

If you dont use true as second parameter for `json_decode` it will return an object

Comment: you have to unset from the array. $value is the data stored at the $key index of the $json array. unset($json[$key]);

Comment: both options didn't help guys, sorry

Comment: i've tried this code and it works perfect, where you've struck exactly ? whats the o/p

Comment: don't know exactly.
changed the description

Answer (score 0):

right code is:

```
<?php
$file = 'data2.json';
$json_data = file_get_contents($file);
$json = json_decode($json_data, true);
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {

        if ($value['id']=='ajson2') {
            unset ($json[$key]);
        }

    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($json));
}
?>
```